# Stop Words function

Tags: php, stop-words

I have this function that returns true if one of the bad words is found in the array `$stopwords`

```
function stopWords($string, $stopwords) {
    $stopwords = explode(',', $stopwords);
    $pattern = '/\b(' . implode('|', $stopwords) . ')\b/i';
    if(preg_match($pattern, $string) > 0) {
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It seems to work fine.

The problem is that when the array `$stopwords` is empty ( so no bad words specified ), it always returns true, like if the empty value is recognized as a bad word and it always returns true ( I think the issue it's this but maybe is another one ).

Can anyone help me sorting out this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I would use `in_array()`:

```
function stopWords($string, $stopwords) {
   return in_array($string, explode(',',$stopwords));
}
```

This will save some time instead of the regexp.

---

EDIT: to match any word in the string

```
function stopWords($string, $stopwords) {
   $wordsArray = explode(' ', $string);
   $stopwordsArray = explode(',',$stopwords);
   return count(array_intersect($wordsArray, $stopwordsArray)) < 1;
}
```

Comment: I am afraid, this fails: `in_array()` will return true, only if **the complete $string** is a stopword, but not if **a word in $string** is a stopword

Comment: @EugenRieck: I've added a solution for checking a single occurrence in a whole string

Comment: @konsolenfreddy ... which gets you a +1 from me!

Answer (score 0):

Give $stopwords as an array

```
function stopWords($string, $stopwords) {
    //Fail in safe mode, if $stopwords is no array
    if (!is_array($stopwords)) return true;
    //Empty $stopwords means all is OK
    if (sizeof($stopwords)<1) return false;
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array `$stopwords` is empty, than `explode(',', $stopwords)` evaluates to an empty string and `$pattern` equals `/\b( )\b/i`. This is the reason why your function returns true if `$stopwords` is empty.

The easiest way to fix it is to add an `if` statement to check whether the array is empty or not.

Answer (score -1):

You can put a condition like this:

```
if (!empty ($stopwords)) { your code} else {echo ("no bad words");}
```

And then ask the user or application to input some bad words.